# How can I launch cron with php XAMPP on Win10?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I want to launch php every 10 sec. Xampp, Win 10.
I've created a bat

```
@echo off
schtasks /Create /TN XAMPP /TR "C:/xampp/php/php-win.exe C:/xampp/htdocs/cron/index.php" /SC MINUTE /MO 1
pause
```

How to launch it, exe, Win panel?

Comment: Windows "scheduled tasks" is not cron.  Ask with proper tags.